# How to set the PYTHONPATH in Jenkins on docker

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins so I'm following this tutorial: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-python-app-with-pyinstaller/#setup-wizard

When I built the project the Build and the Test stages encountered no problem, but on the Deliver stage an error occurred.

This is the log:

```
+ pwd   
+ docker run -v /var/jenkins_home/jobs/python/workspace/8/sources:/src cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python3 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
pyinstaller -F add2vals.py
131 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
132 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
134 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid
135 INFO: wrote /src/add2vals.spec
140 INFO: UPX is available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 114, in run

    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build

    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in main

    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 681, in build

    exec(code, spec_namespace)

  File "/src/add2vals.spec", line 17, in <module>

    noarchive=False)

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 191, in __init__

    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)

ValueError: script '/src/add2vals.py' not found

script returned exit code 1
```

I compared it to the log from the tutorial and besides the python version, another difference is this:

[image: snippet of log from tutorial]

In the Jenkin's configuration system I already added a global variable for PYTHONPATH.
[image]

Is there some set-up that I seem to be missing?

**EDIT**

I changed the image containing the log into the actual log, my mistake.
Also I did not use a Dockerfile, I followed the instructions on the tutorial where it used Jenkinsfile where it downloads images per stage as indicated.

I did not include the steps on the Build and Test stage since there is no problem in their execution.

```
stage('Build') {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.7.5'
        }
    }
}
stage('Test') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'qnib/pytest'
            }
        }
}
stage('Deliver') {
            agent any
            environment {
                VOLUME = '$(pwd)/sources:/src'
                IMAGE = 'cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2'
            }
            steps {
                dir(path: env.BUILD_ID) {
                    unstash(name: 'compiled-results')
                    sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'"
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts "${env.BUILD_ID}/sources/dist/add2vals"
                    sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'rm -rf build dist'"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's a picture of the log, not the log itself.  Can you delete the image and replace it with the actual contents of the log?  Can you provide a [mcve], maybe with enough Jenkins pipeline setup and the image Dockerfile?

Comment: Show your shell of docker run cmd.  From the log,  use option '-w /src' to specify the workdir of container is `/src`, then `pyInstaller` will find `add2vals.py` from `/src`

Comment: @DavidMaze I replaced the image with the actual log. I didn't get to use a Dockerfile since in the tutorial that I was following it was using a Jenkinsfile that supposedly installs the images that I stated.
This is for the Build stage:
`               docker {
                    image 'python:3.7.5'
                }
` 
This is for the Test stage
`
                docker {
                    image 'qnib/pytest'
                }

Comment: @DavidMaze for the Deliver stage it did not download any image for docker, rather it executes this
`
            environment {
                VOLUME = '$(pwd)/sources:/src'
                IMAGE = 'cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2'
            }
            steps {
                dir(path: env.BUILD_ID) {
                    unstash(name: 'compiled-results')
                    sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'"
                }
            }
`
Should I have specified pyinstaller for the docker image?

Comment: Please add these details into the question.  The standard Jenkins Docker integration will mount the workspace directory into the container for you so you don’t need to manually configure this.

Comment: @yong are you referring to the shell command in the Deploy stage? I tried adding '-m /src' just as you said but it returned an error stating that "invalid argument "/src" for "-m, --memory" flag: invalid size: '/src'"

Comment: It's   `-w`   not   `-m`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the work dir of container by `-w` option as following

```
sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} -w /src 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'"
```

the above answer is not valid, it generates this error:
-w /src pyinstaller -F add2vals.py
sh: 0: Illegal option -w
script returned exit code 2

Comment: sorry my mistake, I will try to run the script that you suggested. thanks.